# Extract DLL from within JNA jar file to a custom path

Tags: java, tomcat, dll, jna

The production environment our Java Web Application is deployed in has several permission restrictions, one of them being unable to write in drive C:

We recently added jna-4.1.0.jar and jna-platform-4.1-0.jar dependencies to be able to read Windows Registry but I've noticed that every time server (Tomcat v7.0) is started a DLL file is extracted to a Tomcat temporary folder, giving the following error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp\jna-1319675979\jna1892288885647543043.dll: The handle is invalid`

I've verified that this same DLL is extracted successfully when access permission restriction is removed to ensure this is the source of my problem, but I want to know if there is any way to specify a custom path where that DLL must be extracted to, since we are able to write in drive E:, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DLL you're seeing is JNA's JNI library used to dispatch native calls [[0]](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d93d2a7775a8cbe45777a84924a50479abaf2679/www/GettingStarted.md#getting-started-with-jna). JNA will extract the library to a temporary folder, unless found from the directory specified by the `jna.boot.library.path` property [[1]](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d93d2a7775a8cbe45777a84924a50479abaf2679/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java#L846), or with `System.loadLibrary` [[2]](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d93d2a7775a8cbe45777a84924a50479abaf2679/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java#L912).

The directory used for temporary items can be set with the `jna.tmpdir` property [[3]](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/d93d2a7775a8cbe45777a84924a50479abaf2679/src/com/sun/jna/Native.java#L1203). For example:

```
java -jar program.jar -Djna.tmpdir=E:/temp
```

If `jna.tmpdir` is not set, JNA will use `java.io.tmpdir`.

Notice that at the time of writing, JNA will use `File.mkdirs()` to create the directory structure of the `tmpdir`, so you don't need to make sure the folders exist.

Comment: Now I've set `-Djava.io.tmpdir` to my custom path, let's call it `E:\tmp`, and jna library is indeed extracted there but I keep getting the same error. The OS is a Windows 7 embedded 32-bits. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SergioMerino Might be related to the Java VM's privileges: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:952229840241